# Getting Jmeter property value with jmeter functions

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I get some variable from user.properties to use JSR223 Sampler. In JSR223, I can use as variable such as ${count}, but if this variable pass ${count} to property file, it uses ${count} string instead of value of count variable.

Example:

user.properties:
[image]

In jsr223 sampler:

log.info(props.get("key"));

output => `2023-07-10 12:52:56,884 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: ${count}`

while define count var as 3, jsr223 sampler use ${count}, I want display 3 in log.

Comment: Please add some screenshot and explanation to help people understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the value in `user.properties` will be loaded at the starting time, not in the JMeter runtime. Therefore, the value of `key` is literally `${count}`.

You can override this value at runtime when using `${__setProperty(key,4,)}` in UI element or `props.put("key",5);` in script element (JSR223 Sampers).

Or set value through command line: `jmeter -n -t test-paln.xml -Dkey=6`

Comment: thank a lot, alternatively, literal statement can be handled in jsr223 sampler

Answer (score 0):

There is `props` shorthand which gives you read/write access to JMeter Properties, both pre-defined and user-defined.

So in any [JSR223 test element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) you can access it like:

```
def count = props.get('count')
```

by default it will be a [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) so if you need to perform arithmetic operations like increment you will need to convert it to an appropriate numeric value, for example

```
int count = props.get('count') as Integer
count = count + 1
props.put('count', count)
```

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: I think I misunderstood, I made additions to the question.